# Creating a function that takes an array name as an argument in python. I get the error "unresolved reference to" and then the argument i try to pass

Tags: python, plotly-dash

[error traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyIT4.png) I can't seem to figure out why I can't pass the name of the array as an argument. The function is supposed to take 3 arguments. 1 that is the name of the generated csv file, 1 that is a sql query string (currently the variable MTTR_MTBF that is a select string) and 1 that is the name of array that results of the query are appended to. DataUtlity is class from another file that allows me to take data from sql and use it in pycharm. sql.min_query takes a sql string and returns the results.

```
import csv
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
from sqlConn import DataUtility
import plotly.express as px
sql = DataUtility()
def SQL_to_CSV(file_name: str, sql_str: str, array_name):
    df = pd.DataFrame(sql.min_query(sql_str))
    file_string = "assets/{}".format(file_name)
    df.to_csv(file_string, index=False)
    with open(file_string, 'r') as newFile:
        rd = csv.reader(newFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        array_name = []
        for row in rd:
            array_name.append(row)


SQL_to_CSV("MTTR_MTBF", MTTR_MTBF, so_data)
Total_Time_Scheduled = so_data[1]
```

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Comment: Parameters are for passing values *to* the function; they are evaluated before the function is actually called, so they have to evaluate to something that already exists.  The way you get a value back out of a function is to `return` it, so your call should look something like `so_data = SQL_to_CSV("MTTR_MTBF", MTTR_MTBF)`

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass in an array to the `array_name` parameter, you'd have to actually define something at that variable beforehand. And, in the function itself, you can't do something like `array_name = []`, and have it affect the actual array you passed in, since you didn't declare `array_name` as a global. Thus, any `=` operations won't work on it.

The easiest solution is to create `so_data` and then just pass it in:

```
def SQL_to_CSV(file_name: str, sql_str: str, array_name):
    df = pd.DataFrame(sql.min_query(sql_str))
    file_string = "assets/{}".format(file_name)
    df.to_csv(file_string, index=False)
    with open(file_string, 'r') as newFile:
        rd = csv.reader(newFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in rd:
            array_name.append(row)

so_data = []
SQL_to_CSV("MTTR_MTBF", MTTR_MTBF, so_data)
Total_Time_Scheduled = so_data[1]
```

Or, you can just return `array_name` from the function:

```
def SQL_to_CSV(file_name: str, sql_str: str):
    array_name = []
    df = pd.DataFrame(sql.min_query(sql_str))
    file_string = "assets/{}".format(file_name)
    df.to_csv(file_string, index=False)
    with open(file_string, 'r') as newFile:
        rd = csv.reader(newFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in rd:
            array_name.append(row)
    return array_name


so_data = SQL_to_CSV("MTTR_MTBF", MTTR_MTBF)
Total_Time_Scheduled = so_data[1]
```

Or you can use a global:

```
def SQL_to_CSV(file_name: str, sql_str: str):
    global so_data
    df = pd.DataFrame(sql.min_query(sql_str))
    file_string = "assets/{}".format(file_name)
    df.to_csv(file_string, index=False)
    with open(file_string, 'r') as newFile:
        rd = csv.reader(newFile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in rd:
            so_data.append(row)

so_data = []
SQL_to_CSV("MTTR_MTBF", MTTR_MTBF)
Total_Time_Scheduled = so_data[1]
```

Comment: Returning the array from the function works perfectly for what I'm doing, thank you